# Refresh Cookies for authentication in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I found a tutorial how to create the cookies for the access of Sharepoint online: https://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/#comment-16537

So my application is working now with getting lists using the cookies FedAuth and rtFa (don’t need the request digest). My problem is, that I don’t know when the values of the cookies will expire and if I have to refresh them (and how).
And is there a possibility either to refresh easily my cookie values instead of doing the whole process again or to set that my authentication will not expire?

Comment: hitting this same problem. anyone in the community please help?

Comment: It's definitely greater than 1 minute because in my production application I am able to still make valid requests with a re-used token with a maxTime of hard coded 1 minute before fetching new token.

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable persistent SSO for ADFS - [Configure Persistent Single Sign-On.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-2016-single-sign-on-settings)

By enabling "keep me signed in" `- Set-AdfsProperties –EnableKmsi true` you can check box allowing to keep cookie between browser sessions. Later, when FedAuth cookie expires, you can launch WebBrowser object again and this time, since ADFS cookie is persisted, you don't need to type password again.

Downside is that you need to modify organization's adfs settings.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. We were asking "how long can we reuse the cookies until they expire." the system is configured for persistent single sign-on already.

Comment: you did provide information on the single sign-on settings for ADFS which helps me anyways. I'm awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/session-timeouts-for-office-365-37a5c116-5b07-4f70-8333-5b86fd2c3c40

> 5 days of inactivity as long as the users chooses Keep me signed in. If the user accesses SharePoint Online again after 24 or more hours have passed from the previous sign-in, the timeout value is reset to 5 days.